# Unable to change the JAVA path to the Oracle JDK

Tags: java, rhel

I'm using RHEL8 which has default OpenJDK installed. 
which java command points to /usr/bin/java.
java -version gives openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

Installed java in /u01/app/java/ location. Modified the .bashrc like below & sourced it. 
export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/java/jdk1.8.0_241/ 
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH

Now JAVA_HOME points to /u01/app/java/jdk1.8.0_241/ But which java or java -version still points to the OpenJDK.

- Added the same in .bash_profile file & removed it from the .bashrc : Results are same
- Deleted OpenJDK & made changes in .bash_profile. But by doing so ended up with "Command not found" error.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $PATH` before you run `java -version`?

Comment: $ echo $JAVA_HOME /u01/app/java/jdk1.8.0_241 

$ echo $PATH /home/wcadmin/.local/bin:/home/wcadmin/bin:/u01/app/java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java:/home/wcadmin/.local/bin:/home/wcadmin/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

Answer (score 0):

It was Path issue. 
I have given PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH" for PATH. which should not be the case.
Modified my PATH to below. It worked.

PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

Comment: Yes, the path should only contain directories. In your initial code, you had the path to the Java executable file.